# Outputting the number of records in a database column and assign it as a variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I am wanting to count the id field in my users table in my current query and output that. How can I change my query or my output, so that if there are 40 id's in my user table with the same `WHERE` conditions apply, that I can output it with a variable?

```
$member = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group` IN (2, 3, 4, 5) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$numrows_member = mysqli_num_rows($member);
    if($numrows_member > 0){
        while($row_member = mysqli_fetch_assoc($member)){
            $memberid = $row_member['id'];
            $member_username = $row_member['username'];
        }
    } else {
    $no_members = "No Members Found...";
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `COUNT` simply?

Comment: Because I don't want my other variable or future ones to be counted. Just the id.

Comment: and why are you using LIMIT by 1 ?

Comment: Because with this query I am getting the last user who registered and outputting that name.

Comment: Hi Becky could you please explain bit more your problem...

Comment: My id column from my users table.. I just want to be able to count the total number there are with my current WHERE condition. It is the only column from my users table that I want to count.

Comment: you want to count, how many numbers of user with latest entry with their group is in users table ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

Warning : also rename group column because group is reserve keyword of mysql database in example i renamed it as groupid.

```
<?php
$member = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE `groupid` IN (2, 3, 4, 5) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

$numrows_member = mysqli_num_rows($member);

if($numrows_member > 0){
    $totalRecord=null;
    while($row_member = mysqli_fetch_assoc($member)){
        $memberid = $row_member['id'];
        $member_username = $row_member['username'];

        $group_id = intval($row_member['groupid']);
        if($group_id > 0){ 
            $totalRecord = getTotalRow($con,$group_id);
        }
    }
    echo 'ID : '.$memberid.' UserName : '.$member_username. ' Total records : '.$totalRecord;
} else {
echo $no_members = "No Members Found...";
}

function getTotalRow($con,$id){
    $record=0;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count(id) as total FROM users WHERE groupid = $id ");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        echo $record = $row[0];
    }

    return $record;
}
?>
```